# How to use [CWWiFiClient startMonitoringEventWithType:error:] to get SSID change notification

Tags: macos, wifi

I was trying to get a notification in my OS X machine whenever network is changed.For this i added coreWLAN.framewok. There i found a way as

```
/*!   
 * @method  
 * 
 * @param interfaceName  
 * The name of the Wi-Fi interface.   
 *   
 * @abstract
 * Invoked when the current SSID changes.                                   
 *   
 * @discussion   
 * Use -[CWWiFiClient startMonitoringEventWithType:error:] with the CWEventTypeSSIDDidChange event type   
 * to register for SSID event notifications.    
 * Use -[CWInterface ssidData] or -[CWInterface ssid] to query the current SSID.
 */   
- (void)ssidDidChangeForWiFiInterfaceWithName:(NSString *)interfaceName;
```

But i am not aware of how to use it. Please some one comment here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the same job what you want to achieve in above. It notifies you whenever SSID changes

In order for you to get those notifications you need to be holding on to an instance of CWInterface. Your .h would look like this

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class CWInterface;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (retain) CWInterface *wirelessInterface;

@end
```

Then in your .m file would look like this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreWLAN/CoreWLAN.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize wirelessInterface;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:CWModeDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:CWSSIDDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:CWBSSIDDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:CWCountryCodeDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:CWLinkDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:CWPowerDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    self.wirelessInterface = [CWInterface interfaceWithName:@"en1"];
}

-(void) handleNotification:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Notification Received");
}
```

@end
Take care while using interface name en1 or en0. Check your sysytem by seeing to which interface ip is present by giving ifconfig